# In a taxonomy view, enabling aggregation causes HTML tags in description to be output

Tags: views

I created a view of taxonomy terms and turned on aggregation for the view.

My view shows fields, including the description.

However, when I turn on aggregation, HTML tags are output like this:

```
**Term name: Addition**
<p>Learn about addition.</p>
```

When I turn off aggregation, the HTML tags disappear.

Is this a bug in Views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unintuitive behavior, but it is [Views functioning as designed](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2562941).

To get the HTML tags to render properly, you need to choose **Aggregation settings** for the taxonomy description and check the box *Format* under **Group columns (additional)**.